# 2013 Focus SE Dash Vents not blowing AC or heat, all other vents work fine

Tags: ford, focus, hvac

The climate control in my 2013 Ford Focus doesn't blow anything out of the dash vents. Defrost and floor vents blow fine and I can select between them without issue, but when I select only the dash vents I can hear what sounds like baffles squeaking, but nothing comes out. It is the same for AC and heat. Initially, if I moved back and forth from the dash setting, eventually it would work with the dash vents and they would stay working until I moved to switch to another setting. Where should I start looking for the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting air out of all but the dash, ordinarily that would be an indication that there's a blockage of the dash vent.  But you say you can cycle the selector and eventually get air out of the dash.  That sounds to me like a problem with the selector system.  I'm assuming your car is now out of warranty.  If it was me, I'd pull the climate control panel and see if there were dirty contacts, or replace with a new (or used) panel off a parts car.

[image]